# How to call methods (maybe recursive) itself JAVA

Tags: java, json, methods

Hello I am new in Java and I have a question.
I am using a package to parse JSON Markups but the following problem is this:

```
{
   "example": {
      "subThing": "value"
   },
   "anotherThing" : 0
   ...
}
```

if I call `MyClass.getString("example").getString("subThing");` then I am getting the value of `subThing`.

I want to call these getString() so often as possible ina for loop programmatically with index variable. But I don't know how to do.

```
for(int i = 0;  i > getCurrentState(); i++) {
   //Here I want to call getString();
   //I want in round loop to call getString();
   //In second round loop to call getString().getString();
}
```

Sorry I just started using java 1 week ago.

edit:

I mean how to call `get()` and/or `getString()` programmatically in for loop?

Comment: Which package are you using for JSON parsing?

Comment: You can't call `getString("example")`, because it's not a `String`. It's (a fragment of) a JSON object.

Comment: That index can't return you a method or object. You would need to parse the raw JSON, assuming it has a "keys" method that returns a Set, then would perform depth first search on it. Doesn't need to be recursive

Comment: Sorry it's get(); I am using java2s JSON Parser (org.json.JSONObject).

Comment: Alternatively, rewrite your Java class to automatically extract the inner string to a top level method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you may use the following technique here:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject newObj = new JSONObject("{" +
                "\"data\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "\"id\": 1,\n" +
                "        \"userId\": 1,\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"ABC\",\n" +
                "        \"modified\": \"2014-12-04\",\n" +
                "        \"created\": \"2014-12-04\",\n" +
                "        \"items\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\",\n" +
                "                \"links\": [\n" +
                "                    {\n" +

                "                    }\n" +
                "                ]\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "\n" +
                "}");



        JSONArray items = newObj.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int it = 0; it < items.length(); it++) {
            JSONObject contactItem = items.getJSONObject(it);
            String userName = contactItem.getString("name");


            JSONArray item = contactItem.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                String email = item.getJSONObject(i).getString("email");
                System.out.println(email);
            }

            System.out.println("Name----------" + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

or even better and simpler is to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

For your json is would be smth like this

```
String substring = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.example.subThing", String.class);
String anotherstring = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.anotherThing", String.class);
```